# Tool to migrate field dependencies

Tags: data-loader, picklist, metadata, dependent-picklist

Currently we have several controlling picklist fields that have 300-400 dependent fields under them.
We are doing the field dependency matrix manually in the UI.

Is there any tool that can be used to load

a) picklist values

b) field dependency between a controlling and dependent picklist value 
?

Comment: Facing the same problem. Were you able to find a solution? Can you please share with us here.